# Add custom product attribute to Magento transactional email

Tags: php, magento

I've got a custom attribute (I think that's what it's called, I'm new to Magento.)

This needs to be displayed on some transactional emails via *email/order/items/order/default.phtml*

It looks like this inside the product page view:

```
<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText('designer'); ?>
```

But nothing shows when this is copied into the email template. Have tried a few different things but no luck so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value of that variable than you have set that value to the email template variable.
For example:

```
$emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('test subject');
                                $emailTemplate->setSenderName('your Name');
                                $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail('info@test.com');
                                $emailTemplateVariables = array();
                                $emailTemplateVariables['designer'] = $_product->getAttributeText('designer');
                                $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables);     
                                $emailTemplate->send($email, $emailTemplateVariables);
```

Above notice this

```
$emailTemplateVariables['designer'] = $_product->getAttributeText('designer');
```

This will set the template variable "designer" which you can use in email template.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks, where should these lines be added though?

Comment: you can do it by many different ways.you may have done it in either controller file or there may be an observer where the mail sending functionality has been defined.For example:If you are sending email after order is placed than it will be in sales/controller/ or may be in sales/model/observer.